# When using NLB, only specifying HTTPS works and not HTTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elb

I'm confused with configuring LoadBalancer(NLB) in AWS. When configuring the LB as below (it's the Terraform file), I never specified HTTPS protocol. However, after the LB gets spinned up, I can only reach my targets by `https://LB_ARN:80` and nothing is shown when I hit `http://LB_ARN:80`. I am quite confused of the reason, and also, more confusing part is that using `https://LB_ARN:80` as DNS, my Browser(Chrome) tells me the site is not secure (though it is HTTPS). Any help please ?

```
resource "aws_lb" "boundary" {
  name               = "boundary-nlb"
  load_balancer_type = "network"
  internal           = false
  subnets            = data.terraform_remote_state.network.outputs.tokyo_vpc_main.public_subnet_ids

  tags = merge(local.common_tags, {
    Name = "boundary-${terraform.workspace}-controller-nlb"
    })
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "boundary" {
  name     = "boundary-nlb"
  port     = 9200
  protocol = "TCP"
  vpc_id   = data.terraform_remote_state.network.outputs.tokyo_vpc_main.vpc_id

  stickiness {
    enabled = false
    type    = "source_ip"
  }
  tags = merge(local.common_tags, {
    Name = "boundary-${terraform.workspace}-controller-nlb-tg"
    })
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "boundary" {
  count            = var.num_controllers
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.boundary.arn
  target_id        = aws_instance.controller[count.index].id
  port             = 9200
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "boundary" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.boundary.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "TCP"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.boundary.arn
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "boundary_lb" {
  vpc_id = data.terraform_remote_state.network.outputs.tokyo_vpc_main.vpc_id

  tags = merge(local.common_tags, {
    Name = "boundary-${terraform.workspace}-controller-nlb-sg"
    })
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "allow_9200" {
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 9200
  to_port           = 9200
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.boundary_lb.id
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to me as **misconfiguration** of your backend servers. Specifically, they seem to server HTTPS connections on port 80.

Since you are using NLB with TCP protocol, any HTTPS connection is forwarded to your backend servers. Meaning, there is no SSL termination on your NLB. So even though you haven't specified HTTPS in your NLB settings, HTTPS connections are forwarded on top of TCP to your backend instances. The backend instance handle the HTTPS with maybe self-signed SSL certificate, not NLB, on the wrong port. This would explain warnings from browser.

I would recommend checking configuration of your backend services and making sure that are **serving HTTP on port 80**, not HTTPS as it seems to be the case now.